# Is there any specific formula to be used in finding the following question? What R code do I need to use?

Tags: r

[image]

Is the average SAT score same for graduates and undergraduates? using R

Tried many ways but not sure how to work on R code

```r
mydata3 <- subset(mydata2, Age >= 20 & Age <= 30)
mydata4 <- subset(mydata2, Age >= 20 & Age <= 30, select=c(ID, First, Last, Age))
mydata5 <- subset(mydata2, Gender=="Female" & Status=="Graduate" & Age >= 30)
mydata6 <- subset(mydata2, Gender=="Female" & Status=="Graduate" & Age == 30)
```

tried this and it didn't work

Comment: Can you please provide a minimal reproducible example? Maybe the datapasta package can help.

Regarding the question itself, do you need to conduct a hypothesis testing (i.e., test means)?

Comment: You could use an aggregate function. Something like this: ```ag <- aggregate(SAT_score ~ status, data=df, FUN=mean)```. This will give you the means of graduates and nongraduates. Where SAT_score is whichever column your scores are under. Status is the graduate status column. And df is whatever you named the df.

Comment: However, echoing @pachadotdev, determining if those means are statistically significant is a different question. If you are looking to conduct hypothesis testing, you might consider a t-test, if appropriate (not sure given little info about the data).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Images are not a good way for posting data (or code). See [this Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/8245406) and a [relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/2116/). Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit the question with the code you tried and with the output of `dput(mydata2)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(mydata2, 20))`.